# How to calculate cosine similarity given sparse matrix data in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, cosine-similarity, attention-model

I'm supposed to change part of a python script on the GitHub website. This code is an attention-based similarity measure, but I want to turn it to cosine similarity.

The respective code is in the layers.py file (inside the **call** method).

Attention-Based:

```
  def __call__(self, inputs):
    x = inputs
    # dropout
    if self.sparse_inputs:
        x = sparse_dropout(x, 1-self.dropout, self.num_features_nonzero)
    else:
        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, 1-self.dropout)

    # graph learning
    h = dot(x, self.vars['weights'], sparse=self.sparse_inputs)
    N = self.num_nodes
    edge_v = tf.abs(tf.gather(h,self.edge[0]) - tf.gather(h,self.edge[1]))
    edge_v = tf.squeeze(self.act(dot(edge_v, self.vars['a'])))
    sgraph = tf.SparseTensor(indices=tf.transpose(self.edge), values=edge_v, dense_shape=[N, N])
    sgraph = tf.sparse_softmax(sgraph)
    return h, sgraph
```

I edited the above code to what I believe are my requirements (**cosine similarity**). However, when I run the following code, like so:

```
def __call__(self, inputs):
    x = inputs
    # dropout
    if self.sparse_inputs:
        x = sparse_dropout(x, 1-self.dropout, self.num_features_nonzero)
    else:
        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, 1-self.dropout)

    # graph learning
    h = dot(x, self.vars['weights'], sparse=self.sparse_inputs)
    N = self.num_nodes
    h_norm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(h)
    edge_v = tf.matmul(h_norm, tf.transpose(h_norm))
    h_norm_1 = tf.norm(h_norm)
    edge_v /= h_norm_1 * h_norm_1
    edge_v = dot(edge_v, self.vars['a']) # It causes an error when I add this line
    zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    where = tf.not_equal(edge_v, zero)
    indices = tf.where(where)
    values = tf.gather_nd(edge_v, indices)
    sgraph = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape= [N,N])
    return h, sgraph
```

**The script shows some runtime errors:**

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TDoH.jpg)

I suspect the error here is related to line 226:

```
edge_v = dot(edge_v, self.vars['a']) # It causes an error when I add this line
```

**Any admonition on how to accomplish this successfully?**

Link of the script on GitHub:

https://github.com/jiangboahu/GLCN-tf

**Note:** I don't want to use built-in functions, because I think they are not precise to do this job.

**ETA:** It appears that there are some answers around but they seem to tackle different problems, as far, as I understood them.

Thanks a bunch in advance

Answer (score 0):

What's the **dot**? Have you imported the method?

It should either be:

```
edge_v = tf.keras.backend.dot(edge_v, self.vars['a'])
```

or

```
edge_v = tf.tensordot(edge_v, self.vars['a'])
```